# Allow entering application while in transaction

Tags: sql-server-2016, transaction

We've got a process that needs to run a certain set of stored procedures in a transaction and fail if one of those fails...

Simple we have something similar to:

```
BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            --run some sprocs
            EXEC [dbo].[sproc1];
            EXEC [dbo].[sproc2];
            EXEC [dbo].[sproc3];
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        -- Re-raise error
        EXEC [dbo].[reraise_error];
        RETURN -1;
    END CATCH
```

These sprocs are pretty long running processes.  However, I noticed the team who developed this application was running this job at 10pm and have a step before this job that takes down the site completely.  They wanted to ensure no one edits any of this data so they have the site down while this process happens and then once its done the site is automatically brought back to life.  This has been fine for that past 3 years until we had a customer join us from overseas...they noticed the site was down  (due to this process) and now has requested a change.

I thought simple I could just disable the taking down of the site and handle edits in the front end of my application.  The problem is the database seems to be locked while running this above transaction, for instance, a user trying to get to the site gets a spinning wheel until this transaction completes.

As I ran tests if I comment out the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and just run the sprocs (outside of a transaction) then I no longer have any issue as the tables aren't locked.

But I cannot do that as we want this process to either pass / fail completely.  If it fails we want the whole transaction to fail (as we have a rollback transaction).  The customer still wants the site not to lock up and continue this process so I played around with adding:

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`

But this did not help in any way as it still seems users cannot do anything in the application until after the transaction is complete.

Am I doing something incorrectly?  What can I do so I do not have to lock up the application but continue this process in a transaction?  I would of thought changing the isolation level would help me out but I get the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I ran tests if I comment out the BEGIN TRANSACTION and just run the sprocs (outside of a transaction) then I no longer have any issue as the tables aren't locked.

Inside a transaction, the modification locks are held for the duration of the entire transaction. Without the BEGIN TRAN, locks are only held until the end of each statement.  There will still be blocking, but it won't last as long, so your site is probably able to operate more effectively.

> The customer still wants the site not to lock up and continue this process so I played around with adding:
>
> ```
> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
> ```
>
> But this did not help in any way as it still seems users cannot do anything in the application until after the transaction is complete.

Data modification queries don't work that way.  Check out [the documentation on isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Choosing a transaction isolation level does not affect the locks acquired to protect data modifications. A transaction always gets an exclusive lock on any data it modifies, and holds that lock until the transaction completes, regardless of the isolation level set for that transaction.

What you actually want is the opposite - the nightly process is going to take locks, you want the client (website) to be able to bypass them.  But using `READ UNCOMMITTED` / `NOLOCK` is not the ideal way to do that.  There's a better way, which is

#### Use RCSI

If the web site is mostly reading data, then you might have success with the read committed snapshot isolation level (RCSI).  This would allow the website to continue to read from the database without being blocked by the nightly process.

You can read a detailed account of what to consider when turning on RCSI here: [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/)

Comment: I guess I am confused what I need to do.  All I want to do is allow this stored procedure to execute and not block the site from coming up.  Right now if I run this sproc while simultaneously try to get to the site I get a spinning circle up until this sproc fully completes.  Why can I not somehow get onto the site while this sproc is running when its in a BEGIN TRANSACTION.  If these statements are not in a transaction all is fine.  Its only when they are in a transaction...

Comment: I understand that so your answer is maybe the people who first wrote this application did not consider this therefore they took the whole site down.  Now this would have to be rewritten in a way where the transaction are broken up or made much smaller ?

Comment: I am a bit confused If I enable `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` I would of thought running this process and then trying to get into the application would work, but still no luck.  I would of thought no other changes are needed and that the selects would give me committed data only.  But as this process is running it is blocking logging into the application, etc.  What am I missing here ?

Comment: Maybe the original developers are making a change to stop people connecting (disabling logins or users, disabling an endpoint or various other techniques). So it might nor relate to blocking / transaction isolation level at all.
Time to spin up a 2nd set of servers for the other time zones ?

Comment: @Mo64 - Thats definitely not the case.  Yes I dont know the ins and outs of all of it but that for sure is not the case.  When applying this READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT setting does anything else need to be changed?  A reboot?

Comment: @JonH You shouldn't need to reboot the server.  Can you [run `sp_WhoIsActive @get_additional_info = 1, @get_locks = 1;`](http://whoisactive.com/) on the server while the website is being blocked by the nightly process?  This should help you see what, exactly, is blocking the website from starting up.  Find the session(s) for the website.  The "locks" column will show you what locks it's waiting on, the "additional_info" column will show you the isolation level of the website's query, and the  blocking_session_id should show the session of the nightly process.

Comment: @JoshDarnell - Thanks that helped let me continue to investigate what is causing this MESS!